# what is the purpose of CONST_ID() in ruby and what are the advantages over rb_intern()?

Tags: c, ruby

In c extensions to ruby, to call a method you can do

```
rb_funcall(object, rb_intern("method name"), argumentcount, arg1, arg2, …);
```

where rb_intern() returns some internal represantation of the method name.
I have seen some code which does instead

```
ID method;
CONST_ID(method, "method name");
rb_funcall(object, method, argumentcount, arg1, arg2, …);
```

What exactly is the difference beetwen rb_intern() and CONST_ID. Which advantages does CONST_ID() have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CONST_ID` macro calls `rb_intern2` (which is about the same as `rb_intern`) to get the ID, but there is one big difference.  If you look at the `CONST_ID` macro source in `include/ruby/ruby.h`, you'll see that it starts a new block and defines a static `ID` variable to cache the result.  If, next time that block is executed, the static variable is already set, it just returns the cached result instead of searching for the `ID` all over again.

So they do the same thing, but `CONST_ID` should be faster for multiple lookups of the same string.